# Python list tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Say,

```
data = { 123: 1, 234: 2, 241: 4 }
a = list(sorted(data.items()))
```

Isn't list unnecessary ? I think, `sorted(data.items())` itself will return `list` of `tuples` ? Why would anyone use list function specifically ?

Comment: It is unnecessary in this case. So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sorted` returns a `list` itself. So, calling `list()` on a `list` data structure is useless. Calling `list()` on it is equivalent to `sorted(data.items())[:]`.

```
In [7]: print sorted.__doc__
sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list

In [8]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [9]: lis
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]

In [10]: list(lis)    #same result, but different object. (A shallow copy)
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3]
```

`list()` can be useful if you want to fetch all the values of an `iterator` :

```
In [11]: y=xrange(5)

In [12]: y
Out[12]: xrange(5)

In [13]: list(y)
Out[13]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

The `list` call is unnecessary in this case—you're correct.

Some Python methods return iterators rather than lists. The `list` function can be used to **force the iterator to become a list** (so that it can be indexed, for example).

Take the function [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), for example, which returns an iterator:

```
In [1]: type(reversed([3,1,2]))
Out[1]: listreverseiterator

In [2]: reversed([3,1,2])[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

We can use `list` to consume the iterator and use its results in a list:

```
In [3]: list(reversed([3,1,2]))[1]
Out[3]: 1
```

`list` might be used to **force other list-like types to be concrete lists**:

```
In [4]: (1,2,3).append(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

In [5]: list((1,2,3)).append(4) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: +1. The key to the OP's question is probably that whoever wrote that wasn't positive whether `sorted` returned a list or not, and, instead of thinking about it or just testing it out in an interpreter, decided to add an extra `list` to be safe.

Comment: IIRC, `sorted` returns a generator-view thingy in Python 3, so wrapping it with a call to `list` is useful in that context. (EDIT: it appears I am wrong: unlike a lot of other functions, `sorted` still returns a list even in Python 3.3)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in this case it is unnecessary :-)